# How to determine field type in Netsuite Suite Script?

Tags: netsuite

I am creating a RESTlet that is used to update fields in a Netsuite entity.  This works no problem for standard Text fields in Netsuite yet for updating Date fields it requires a seperate method, and updating List fields requires knowing the enum value.

My question is, in my RESTlet, given a field id such as "custevent_date_field" how can I lookup from Netsuite what kind of field it is so I can use the appropriate setField approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getType()` function on an `nlobjField` object.

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord('invoice', '1393440');

var field1 = record.getField('entity');
var field2 = record.getField('trandate');

var type1 = field1.getType();  // type1 contains 'select'
var type2 = field2.getType();  // type2 contains 'date'
```